# What's the correct way to detect whether SOCKS proxies are supported with Python requests?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, socks, pysocks

Modern versions of `requests` support HTTP(S) proxies out-of-the-box, and also [SOCKS proxies](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#socks). However the latter are “an optional feature that requires that additional third-party libraries be installed before use.” [PySocks](https://pypi.org/project/PySocks/) is the appropriate third-party library on all POSIX-like platforms that I am familiar with.

I'm building an application that uses `requests` with a user-configurable proxy, and trying to figure out how to test for whether SOCKS proxies will be supported by the local installation of `requests`.

As far as I can tell, the `requests` API does not contain a built-in function to check for this support, but when the library attempts to actually *use* a SOCKS5 proxy, it will raise the exception `InvalidSchema("Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.")`.

I've come up with the following incantation to try to test for whether `requests` supports SOCKS proxies ahead of using them…

```py
try:
    requests.adapters.SOCKSProxyManager('socks5://')
    have_socks = True
except requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema:
    have_socks = False
```

This appears to work correctly (tested with `requests` 2.22.0) but doesn't seem particularly future-proof.

Is there a better (simpler, safer, more future-proof) way to test for SOCKS support in `requests`, before using it?

Comment: What about that doesn't seem future-proof? Looks like you're testing for exactly the feature you care about.

Comment: Thanks. However… as far as I can tell, the `requests.adapters` classes are not really intended as a public feature of the API, and may not be stable across releases. I'm also not certain that the use of the `InvalidSchema` exception here is intended to be stable, nor that the truncated proxy URI `'socks5://'` will continue to be accepted across releases.

Comment: Are you trying to check whether Pysocks is installed?

Comment: @AMC, I suppose I _could_ do that, but I don't know that success of `import socks` is a necessary, sufficient, and _stable_ condition to ensure that `requests` will support SOCKS proxies. (Also, the flexible wording of the `requests` docs suggests that some other libraries might be used to support SOCKS proxies on other platforms.)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If I understand correctly all you need is a version of requests which supports the optional feature plus a compatible version of the pysocks library, no?

Comment: @AMC, yes, you're right. That may indeed be a sufficient condition to guarantee the SOCKS proxy works. I just wish I had some authoritative source to verify that this is correct and not likely to change in a future API version.